# Is there a way to listen watch / subscribe in Vue composition + Pinia from a different component than which tiggered the state change

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuex, pinia

Technologies :  Vue, Pinia & Composition API

I have a scenario which has 2 windows opened simultaneously for the same application.

Lets say there are 2 different Vue components (A & B) & a store which doesn't have parent child relationship.

Have written watch / subscribe in both A & B components. I want watch / have a listener in component A when a state is changed in store from component B.

Looks like watch / subscribe are fired only from the component the action is called. For example if I call a action from B, then B's watch / subscribe is fired and A's are never fired.

Is there a way to trigger Component A's watch / subscribe or is there a different way to communicate between store and components.

```
Component A : 


<script setup>
  import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'
  import { useUser } from './store/user/user.store'

  const userStore = useUser()
  const { isLoggedIn } = storeToRefs(userStore)
  
  userStore.$subscribe((mutation, state) => {
    console.log(mutation, state)
  })

</script>

<template>

</template>
```

Component B :

```
<script setup>
  import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'
  import { useUser } from './store/user/user.store'

  const userStore = useUser()
  const { isLoggedIn } = storeToRefs(userStore)

  userStore.updateMyValue("blah")

  userStore.$subscribe((mutation, state) => {
    console.log(mutation, state)
  })

</script>

<template>

</template>
```

Store :

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useUser = defineStore('user', {
  state: () => ({
    myValue: "Hello",
  }),
  actions: {
    updateMyValue(val) {
      this.myValue= val
    },
  },
})
```

Any suggestions to listen to state updates from a different component is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: It's unclear which components are in which window. The communication between windows is a separate topic. If you need it with Pinia, some plugin that makes use of localstorage or broadcast channel events can be used, e.g. pinia-shared-state

Comment: Component A is in window 1 and Component B is in window 2(To be clear, both the components are part of same web applications).   Hope this helps. Also May I ask your thoughts of using event bus in this scenario vs pinia-shared-state

Comment: It doesn't really matter which comps they are because they run in different app instances. pinia-shared-state already uses BroadcastChannel event bus. If you use event bus directly, you'd need to additionally sync the store and do the work that the plugin does